# Dividing grouped data by group means r

Tags: r

I have data split up into two categories:

```
z= Tracer time treatment
    15 0 S
    20 0 S
    25 0 X
    04 0 X
    55 15 S
    16 15 S
    15 15 X
    20 15 X
```

I'd like to divide each value of Tracer by the group mean depending on which group it belongs to (e.g. All values of Tracer belonging to time=0 and treatment=S are divided by their mean).

The procedure would be something like this:
Find category means as follows:

1:

```
aggmeanz <-aggregate(z$Tracer, list(time=z$time,treatment=z$treatment), FUN=mean)
```

2: Divide `z$Tracer` by the correct `aggmeanz` value

```
structure(list(Tracer = c(15L, 20L, 25L, 4L, 55L, 16L, 15L, 20L
), time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), treatment = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("S", "X"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Tracer", 
"time", "treatment"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, here is a dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(z,time,treatment) %>% 
  mutate(pmean=Tracer/mean(Tracer))
```

Output:

```
  Tracer  time treatment     pmean
   (int) (int)    (fctr)     (dbl)
1     15     0         S 0.8571429
2     20     0         S 1.1428571
3     25     0         X 1.7241379
4      4     0         X 0.2758621
5     55    15         S 1.5492958
6     16    15         S 0.4507042
7     15    15         X 0.8571429
8     20    15         X 1.1428571
```

Data:

```
z <- read.table(text="Tracer time treatment
15 0 S
20 0 S
25 0 X
04 0 X
55 15 S
16 15 S
15 15 X
20 15 X",head=TRUE)
```

Comment: > library(dplyr)
> zftt<-group_by(z,time,treatment)
> mutate(pmean=Tracer/mean(Tracer))
Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Comment: you forgot the pipe `%>%` : `zftt<-group_by(z,time,treatment) %>% mutate(pmean=Tracer/mean(Tracer))`. It sends the output of `group_by` as the first argument of `mutate`

Comment: Ahhh, my mistake, I didn't realise what that was. Someone told me it was a comment. :-). Also out of all these solutions, this seems to be the fastest...

Answer (score 2):

Is it ok to use non-base tools? With `data.table` installed and loaded:

```
z <- data.table(z)
z[, scaledTracer := Tracer/mean(Tracer), by = c("time","treatment")]
```

Would compute means by each unique combination of `time` and `treatment` (which appear to be groups of 2 rows in your data), and scale the `Tracer` values in each group by the appropriate mean.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the prettiest but:

```
 groupmeans = aggregate(z$Tracer, by = list(z$time, z$treatment), FUN = mean)

  Group.1 Group.2    x
       0       S 17.5
      15       S 35.5
       0       X 14.5
      15       X 17.5
 names(groupmeans) = c("time", "treatment", "groupmean")
 z = merge(z, groupmeans, id.vars = c("time","treatment" ))

 time treatment groupmean Tracer tracer_div
    0         S      17.5     15  0.8571429
    0         S      17.5     20  1.1428571
    0         X      14.5     25  1.7241379
    0         X      14.5      4  0.2758621
   15         S      35.5     55  1.5492958
   15         S      35.5     16  0.4507042
   15         X      17.5     15  0.8571429
   15         X      17.5     20  1.1428571

z$tracer_div = z$Tracer/z$groupmean

 time treatment groupmean Tracer tracer_div
    0         S      17.5     15  0.8571429
    0         S      17.5     20  1.1428571
    0         X      14.5     25  1.7241379
    0         X      14.5      4  0.2758621
   15         S      35.5     55  1.5492958
   15         S      35.5     16  0.4507042
   15         X      17.5     15  0.8571429
   15         X      17.5     20  1.1428571
```

You could reassign z$Tracer to the final step if you didn't want to create a whole new column. It can be nice to keep every step though in case you want to use it in another calculation or plot later.

Comment: Thank you for this, I think it's going to be a method I'll keep in mind for next time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

a base R solution:

```
do.call(c, lapply(split(z[1], z[, -1]), FUN = function(x) x[[1]]/mean(x[[1]])))

    # 0.S1      0.S2     15.S1     15.S2      0.X1      0.X2     15.X1     15.X2 
#0.8571429 1.1428571 1.5492958 0.4507042 1.7142857 0.2857143 0.8571429 1.1428571
```

split into `time`x`treatment` groups first, then divide each group by mean. finally glue back together with `c`.

Comment: Thank you, your help is much appreciated. I like it because it looks straight forward

Comment: Can the final result still be in table form Tracer time treatment?

Comment: @HCAI it's not the most concise, `dplyr` above is more elegant, but yes like you say i guess it's more understandable if you are not familiar with `dplyr` etc. you can append it back to your table via for example `cbind(z, mean = do.call(c, lapply(split(z[1], z[, -1]), FUN = function(x) x[[1]]/mean(x[[1]]))))`. is this what you are asking for?