# R DataFrame Quick Manipulation by Collection of Rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R, its first few rows look like this:

```
User_Name       Product      Score
  John             1          1.5
  John             2          0.5
  John             3          0.1
  Tim              1          2
  Tim              2          2
  Tim              3          1
```

What I am trying to do is for each User_Name, "normalize" the product scores by dividing by the max of the scores for that user. I.e., I would get:

```
User_Name       Product      Score
      John             1          1
      John             2          0.333
      John             3          0.0667
      Tim              1          1
      Tim              2          1
      Tim              3          0.5
```

So far I have done this using a for loop and subsetting the dataframe for each unique user then appending all the results to a new dataframe using rbind(). However, as my dataframe becomes very large, this will seemingly take too long. I was wondering if there was a more fast "R-way" :) to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Comment: Using `dplyr` , `df %>%
  group_by(User_Name) %>%
  mutate(Score = Score/max(Score))
`

Comment: Thanks! But, out of curiosity is there a non-dplyr solution?

Comment: There must be something for `max` as well somewhere but you could use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339270/dividing-grouped-data-by-group-means-r and replace `mean` with `max`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ave` from base R

```
df$Score1 <- with(df, Score/ave(Score, User_Name, FUN = max))

df
#  User_Name Product Score Score1
#1      John       1   1.5 1.0000
#2      John       2   0.5 0.3333
#3      John       3   0.1 0.0667
#4       Tim       1   2.0 1.0000
#5       Tim       2   2.0 1.0000
#6       Tim       3   1.0 0.5000
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(User_Name) %>% mutate(Score = Score/max(Score))
```

and for completeness `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Score1 := Score/max(Score), by = User_Name]
```